# Integration from Schrodinger and Dirac solution in momentum space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, dirac-equation, differential-equations

I asked myself this questions to understand wave equations but couldn't solve them:

(I hope answer of first question be yes, and the second one no, as a result of relativistic effect of probability of creation new or annihilation of our particle.)

1. Let $\Psi$ be a solution for the (not necessarily free) Schrodinger equation. From Fourier transform in momentum space we have some thing like this:
   $$\Psi(x,t) = \int dpe^{i\frac{p}{h}x}\Phi(p,t)$$
   Is it true that for every fixed $t$, the function $|\Phi(p,t)|^2$ is probability distribution of finding the particle by momentum $p$? Could we prove that
   $$\int dp|\Phi(p,t)|^2=1 \qquad ?$$
   (where $t$ is arbitrarily fixed and integration is in 3dimensional momentum space)
2. Do we have analog proposition and proof for solution of (not necessarily free) Dirac equation?

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer one of your questions:

1. Starting from
   $$\Psi(x,t) = \int \frac{dp}{(2\pi\hbar)}e^{i\frac{p}{\hbar}x}\Phi(p,t)$$
   for a normalized wave function (recall that a normalized wave function remains normalized in time), one can demonstrate that
   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dp}{(2\pi\hbar)}|\Phi(x,t)|^2=
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx e^{ipx/\hbar}\Psi^*(x,t)
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx' e^{-ipx'/\hbar}\Psi(x',t)$$
   and performing the integral with respect to the momentum yields
   $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dp}{(2\pi\hbar)}|\Phi(x,t)|^2=
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \Psi^*(x,t)
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx' \Psi(x',t)
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dp e^{ip(x-x')/\hbar}=
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \Psi^*(x,t)
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx' \Psi(x',t)\
   \delta(x-x')=
   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \Psi^*(x,t)\Psi(x,t)=1$$
   since the wave function is normalized.
2. One can also Fourier transform the solution to the Dirac equation. The normalization, however, will be that of a spinor, as opposed to that of a function. The probability should be conserved in time, in the case of the Dirac equation, as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: My second question also says "solution of Dirac's equation".  Am I wrong? @schris38

Comment: I do not understand what the second question is? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Thanks for following up on my question. In question it starts with "2. Do we have analog...". I want to explore Fourier transform of function $\Psi$ (solution of (not necessarily free) Dirac equation) to momentum space and see if just like the case of Schrodinger solution it's square amplitude integral (or some thing like this) over 3-momemtum space is constant in time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to divide the $dp$ by $2\pi$:
$$
\psi(x,t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dp}{2\pi}\phi(p,t)
$$
before $\phi(p,t)$ becomes a probability. I.e so that
$$
\int  _{-\infty}^\infty dx|\psi(x,t)|^2=1 
$$
implies that
$$
\int  _{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dp}{2\pi} |\phi(p,t)|^2=1.
$$
This follows from
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx e^{ix(p-p')} = 2\pi \delta(p-p').
$$

Comment: Is it not important with which differential equation we work? Schrodinger, Dirac, or some thing else. Solution of an arbitrary differential equation could simply violate from conservation of (square of) integral in different times.

Comment: It's nothing to do with time. It's just Fourier transforms.

Comment: I think when you are using $\int \Psi^2 =1$ as a middle step of your proof you are considering Schrodinger equation and time in a implicit manner. Because proving just sated equality needs to know what differential equation we are working with and is it have stability of integral in time. @mike